# "Not to ask for "—what's it's meaning? Is this idiomatic?

Tags: meaning-in-context, idiomatic-language

**Not to ask for** a man,I love animals too.

Is the bolded part idiomatic?

Comment: Did you write this yourself?  What makes you doubt this phrase?  When asking questions try to avoid simple yes/no questions about a random example.

Comment: What is it supposed to mean? Where did you hear it? It might be idiomatic in some circumstance but sounds a bit odd sitting there on its own. "Not to be awkward" and similar are sometimes used meaning "I don't want to be awkward", although I'm not sure of precise geographical distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps in some *regional* dialect, which the author is trying to convey, but I've never seen "Not to ask for a man", and searching online for that turns up nothing. Another possibility is that it's recorded dialog as misheard.